# Creating Kerberos tickets for Team City users in agents

Tags: teamcity, kerberos

Is there a secure way for allowing Team City users to create their Kerberos tickets in the agents? For additional context, I have a Team City build configuration that allows users to partially automate things and one thing it does is that a build step requires that a user to be authenticated via Kerberos in order to access some resource. The solution I have right now is to ask for the users credentials in order to create the ticket in the agent. But if possible, as much as I could I don't want for the build to ask sensitive information. Is there a way to do it more securely?

Answer (score 0):

The solution I used right now is for a user to generate a kerberos keytab in their local machine, encode the file to Base64 and use the encoded string as a team city parameter that will be used for authorization. It seems better than asking for the user's password.